# Instalar PHP Extension intl no alojamento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Bom dia, ao instalar o Magento2 deparei-me com a falta de uma extensão do php. "Intl". Gostaria de saber como instalar a extensão no meu alojamento, o qual só tenho acesso por cpanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

em localhost seria apenas abrir o php.ini e encontrar **extension=php_intl.dll** que vai estar marcada como comentário, desmarque e reinicie o servidor.

Por Cpanel você poderia verificar em PHP Configuration, no meu caso não encontrei, e entrar em contato com seu sevidor.